# Android Kotlin Singleton

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, singleton

I'm new to android and kotlin. But, I've read some articles about `intent`.

so in this project, I want to store an `authKey` from API to this `intent` but I noticed something that this authKey only used on activity that we defined on `startActivity` like this

```
startActivity(
     Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).putExtra("credentials",
           response.getJSONObject("data").getString("authKey")
           )
)
```

I also read about `singleton`, and I want to know what is `singleton` and how to implement this to my authKey issue.

can any body help me with this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store this `authKey` in your Singleton object, you can implement it as follows code:

```kotlin
object AuthKeyStore {
    private var _authKey: String? = null
    
    val authKey: String?
        get() = _authKey
    
    fun putAuthKey(key: String) {
        _authKey = key
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```kotlin
 /**
     * This only mock for api request returned.
     */
    fun getResponseFromApi(response: Response) {
        val data = response.getJSONObject("data")
        if (data != null) {
            val authKey = data.getString("authKey")
            AuthKeyStore.putAuthKey(authKey)
        }
    }
```

At last, you can get this `authKey` in other activities by:

```kotlin
  val storedAuthKey = AuthKeyStore.authKey
```

Comment: You can create a public `var` with `private set` written under it to avoid having to create a second property.